# Algorithm to find 'hot spots' in a database of GPS coordinates

Tags: algorithm, geolocation, coordinates, geospatial

I've got an amount of data that I'm about to put into a database, it's a list of GPS points.

I want to iterate over this database and create a table of 'hot spots' where there are a high number of database points in a certain size of area (either a square area, or a circular area - I don't need to be exact).

Can anyone recommend existing algorithms that might help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

r3mo

Comment: This might be better asked over at http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K-Means clustering would be a good starting point, for identifying hot-spots. See [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a raster with a given cell size and assigning the raster value to the number of points falling within each pixel (a density plot)? It's a basic approach with some limitations (where you place the grid and the pixel size will affect the outcome), but if that's all you need... This could be accomplished easily in R using the spatstat package. Check out [this pdf tutorial](http://www.csiro.au/files/files/pn0y.pdf) on spatstat for examples.

Unless another variable is attached to your points, it's not really hotspot detection, just a determination of point density...